# How to determine whether a particular resource has data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out the proper way to get file location data (for display/editing) from MySQL with PHP. So far I've got these three parts. $resfile is a resource getting the actual array. Would I then test with an if statement, or would I have to use a while loop to iterate over the array (which, as far as I know, should only have ONE value)

First part:

```
$resfile = mysql_query('SELECT file_loc WHERE org_id = '.$org);
```

Do I use this?

```
if (!$resfile) {

}
```

Or this?

```
while ($filerow = mysql_fetch_array($resfile)) {

}
```

Or both?

Comment: You look like you are starting off in PHP, may i suggest you take the mysql_num_rows just to make it work but then switch immediately to MySQLi. I've had lots of trouble letting the "mysql_" functions go but since you're starting out, i'd recommend you take the right road right off the start...

Answer (score 5):

The mySQL library has [a function](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) for counting the rows of a result set:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($resfile) > 0) .......
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use both. If the query returns false, then there was an error executing your query.  If there is no data returned in the query, (it will still return true) then you need to use fetch_array to get the data.